# Como actualizar las 'abilities' en Laravel 7 con Sanctum

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

Estoy desarrollando un api con laravel 7, donde los usuarios se registran. Al momento de iniciar sesión se generara un token con Sanctum, A su vez se le asignan las abilities y se guarda en una BD.
Este seria el codigo que se ejecuta al momento de iniciar sesion y se le asignan las abilities:

```
public function login(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'email'=> 'required|email',
        'password'=> 'required',
    ]);

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if(! $user || ! Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => ['Email o password incorrectos'],
        ]);
    }      
    $token = $user->createToken($request->email,['user:user'])->plainTextToken; //aqui asigno las abilities
    
    return response()->json(["token" => $token],201);
}
```

Este seria el resultado en mi BD:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora para modificar estas abilities tengo este codigo que reemplaza la abilities anterior y le asigna uno nuevo.

```
public function asignar_rol(Request $request,$id){
        $request->validate([
            'nuevo_rol'=> 'required',
        ]);
        
        $nuevo_rol = $request->nuevo_rol; 

        $array_roles =[
            $nuevo_rol,
        ];
        DB::table('personal_access_tokens')->where('tokenable_id', $id)->update(['abilities'=>$array_roles]);   
        
        return $array_roles;
}
```

Y se sigue respetando las misma estrucutra.

Mi pregunta es como le puedo añadir una nueva abilitie sin reemplazar la anterior y mantener la estructura.
Es decir tengo mi abilitie y le asigno una nueva, por ejemplo "admin:admin".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el resultado que espero en mi BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las abilities las utilizo para restringir rutas de mi api haciéndole saber a los usuario que no están autorizados para consumir dicha ruta, Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Primero, obtener el usuario:

   ```
    $user = DB::table('personal_access_tokens')
       ->where('tokenable_id', $id);
   ```
2. Convertir el string, de sus `abilities`, a un array:

   ```
    $abilities = json_decode($user->first()->abilities);
   ```
3. Agregar la nueva ability al array que obtuviste:

   ```
    array_push($abilities, "admin:admin");
   ```
4. Finalmente, sólo debes convertir el array a string y actualizar el usuario:

   ```
    $user->update([
         "abilities" => json_encode($abilities)
    ]);
   ```